# How NodeJs implements listen() function of http package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, server

I'm trying to understand how nodeJs implements listen() for it's http server. I tried looking into the source code but it was not so helpful.

Can anybody explain how listen() function runs forever (Is there a infinite loop or setInterval that makes it happen?)

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Comment: Read how TCP works at socket level (listen, bind, accept). No magic, just wrapping what your operating system already does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a timer is needed to keep the process running, because it is an `I/O` event - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll.

> Between each run of the event loop, Node.js checks if it is waiting for any **asynchronous I/O** or timers and shuts down cleanly if there are not any.